# Pattern Matching in 2-dimensional lists

Tags: data, searching

How would I search for all the elements in a nested list which contain values at specific index? For example, I want to search for and return all the elements in a (n,2) list which begin with a 3 ({3, ...}).

How would I generalize it to return all elements of a list which begin with a 3 of any length, or of a fixed length if the inner lists are of variable length?

Comment: I'm not totally sure what you mean by "at a specific index", but assuming your overall list is something like `a = {{1,0},{3,6,7},{2,5}}`, try `Cases[a, {3, ___}]`. Note that `_` matches a single expression, `__` matches one or more expressions, and `___` matches zero or more expressions. To match exactly `n` expressions, you could use `Repeated`: `{3, Repeated[_, {n}]}`. (There are also syntax variations to match up to `n` expressions, between `n` and `m`, etc.; see the docs for `Repeated`.) (You can also find elements on different levels by giving a level specification for `Cases`.)

Comment: A concrete $ n $-by-2 list will be appreciated, I guess.

Comment: Or, maybe, `Pick[a, a[[All,1]],3]`

Answer (score 2):

Let's create a list of lists with varying lengths:

```
SeedRandom[2];
list = Table[
  RandomInteger[{0, 9}], {i, 20}, {j, RandomInteger[{1, 4}]}];
```

We can now select lists that all start with 3, but have varying lengths:

```
Cases[list, {3, _}]  (*exactly 2 elements*)

Cases[list, {3, _, _}] (*exactly 3 elements*)

Cases[list, {3, __}] (*at least 2 elements*)

Cases[list, {3, ___}] (* at least 1 element *)
```

[image]